# JUnit + Mockito тестирование исключения

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "api/message/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteMessage(@PathVariable Long id) {
    messageService.delete(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Нужно проверить на исключение если запросить удаление несуществующего id.

Возвращает

```
{
"timestamp": 1483566196066,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException",
"message": "No class com.sttech.springrest.model.Message entity with id 1000 exists!",
"path": "/api/message/1000"
}
```

Тест метод

```
@Test(expected = EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)
    public void deleteMessageIfNotFoundThenException() {
    messageController.deleteMessage(2L);
}
```

Возвращает ошибку

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException

Если так:

```
@Test(expected = EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)
public void deleteMessageIfNotFoundThenException1() {
    when(messageController.deleteMessage(2L));
    then(caughtException())
            .isInstanceOf(EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)
            .hasMessageContaining("entity with id 2 exists!");
}
```

Возвращает ошибку

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException> but was<java.lang.AssertionError>
```

Вообще это исключение надо тестировать в контроллере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тестировать надо только, если есть поведение. В ваше случае можете проверить, что контроллер вызвал у сервиса/репозитории правильный метод и вернул правильный результат. Я бы исключение не тестировал, но если вы хотите, то можно вот так

```
@Test(expected = EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)
public void deleteMessageIfNotFoundThenException1() {
    when(messageService.delete(2L)).thenThrow(new EmptyResultDataAccessException());
    messageController.deleteMessage(2L);
}
```

Если вы делаете REST сервис, то операция DELETE должна быть idempotent, т.е. состояние системы не меняется, даже если метод был вызван несколько раз (N>0) подряд.